# How can I convert a LaTeX document to Texinfo format?

Tags: conversion, xml, texinfo

I have a LaTeX document, and I'd like to produce from it a [Texinfo](http://www.gnu.org/s/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html) document. Does there exist a tool that does this, or a set of guidelines? TeX and Texinfo seem to be closely related, so it feels like it should be possible, but I can't seem to find anything that does this conversion in particular.

If there is no general tool for that, how much information am I likely to lose in going from LaTeX to XML to Texinfo?

The document in question is the [LaTeX source of the Mongrel2 manual](https://github.com/mongrel2/mongrel2/tree/master/docs/manual), for reference - so it's a non-trivial chunk of TeX, but also guaranteed not to be a malformed or perverse chunk of TeX.

Comment: Yeah, if there's no answer in a few days, I'm going to flag this for moderator attention and request a move.  Thank you.

Comment: There is [this at tug.org](http://www.tug.org/tds/tds2texi.el).

Comment: Usually the sequence is in the reverse direction ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). Pandoc uses "[templates](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates)" to convert an input format into [pandoc's markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#pandocs-markdown) format, which can then be converted into any other format with a supported template. The official [templates repository](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates) lists both `texinfo` and `latex` templates, so that's where I'd start.

Comment: Awesome!  Pandoc worked.  Pandoc also exposed the fact that this TeX document lacks a bunch of stuff I'm used to finding in Texinfo documents. So I'm getting an education in how to construct those. I hope Zed doesn't make enough changes to the manual that I have to do this again soon.

Comment: Glad to help, and good luck.